# Управление фрагментами с ViewPager в NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

Есть созданный `NavigationDrawer`, к нему подключены табы. Получается так, что первый самый `Item` с табами (фрагментами) в дровере работает корректно, а уже 2-ой выводит ту же информацию (`TextView`), ту что находиться в первом `Item` и в его табах.
Подскажите как это исправить, в коде, если можно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, собственно, сам код 2-ого итема и его табов в активити:

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.activity_main;

        private Drawer.Result drawerMenu;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setTheme(R.style.myTheme2);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(LAYOUT);
            initTabs();


            // Инициализируем Toolbar
            toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            if (toolbar !=null) {
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }

            initializeNavigationDrawer(toolbar);


        }

private void initTabs() {
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    // Инициализируем TabLayout

    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    TabFragmentFish adapter = new TabFragmentFish(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerMenu != null && drawerMenu.isDrawerOpen()) {
        drawerMenu.closeDrawer();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

//Инициализация Дравера
private void initializeNavigationDrawer(Toolbar toolbar) {
            drawerMenu = new Drawer()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
            .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
            //Добавление Итемов в шторку
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                            .withName(R.id.aqua_fish)
                            .withIdentifier(1)
                            .withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_circle),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                            .withName(R.id.aqua_plant)
                            .withIdentifier(2)
                            .withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_leaf),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                            .withName(R.id.aqua_water)
                            .withIdentifier(3)
                            .withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_tint),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                            .withName(R.id.aqua_lighting)
                            .withIdentifier(4)
                            .withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_lightbulb_o),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                            .withName(R.id.aqua_co2)
                            .withIdentifier(5)
                            .withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_circle),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem()
                            .withName(R.id.aqua_filtration)
                            .withIdentifier(6)
                            .withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_filter),
                    //--------------------------------------------- Secondary
                    new DividerDrawerItem(),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem()
                            .withName(R.id.about)

                            .withIdentifier(7),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem()
                            .withIdentifier(8)
                            .withName(R.id.exit))
                    //Реализуем клик по айтэмам
                    .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                            switch (drawerItem.getIdentifier()){
                                case 1:
                                    TabFragmentFish adapter = new TabFragmentFish(getSupportFragmentManager());
                                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                                    break;

                                case 2:
                                    TabFragmentAdapterPlants adapterPlants = new TabFragmentAdapterPlants(getSupportFragmentManager());
                                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterPlants);
                                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                                    break;

                                //Мини окошко "Об авторе с закрытием ОК"
                                case 7:
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                                    builder
                                            .setTitle("Об авторе")
                                            .setMessage("Автор:Артем Мишуровский"+"\n\nEmail: artm.mishurovskiy@gmail.com")
                                            .setCancelable(false)
                                            .setNegativeButton("Ок", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                                                }
                                            });
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                                    alertDialog.show();
                                    break;
                                //Выход из программы
                                case 8:
                                    finish();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    })
            .build();

  }

}
```

Сам адаптер и в нем созданы табы:

```
public class TabFragmentAdapterPlants extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

//Create massive
private String[] tabs;
private FragmentTransaction fTrans;

public TabFragmentAdapterPlants(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

    //Create tabs
    tabs= new String[] {
            "Растения",
            "Болезни растений",
            "Водоросли"
    };

}



//Получение позиции Табов что б передать их в свитч
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabs[position];
}


//Переключение между фрагменами с помощью позиции 0,1,2
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return FragmentPlants.getInstance();
        case 1:
            return FragmentsPlantsDisease.getInstance();
        case 2:
            return FragmentPlantsAlgae.getInstance();
    }

    return null;
}


//табс в ширину !!
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.length;
}
}
```

Фрагмент, на который переключается адаптер:

```
public class FragmentPlants extends Fragment {

private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragments_plants2;

private View view;

public static FragmentPlants getInstance(){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    FragmentPlants fragmentPlants = new FragmentPlants();
    fragmentPlants.setArguments(args);

    return fragmentPlants;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать нужное количество фрагментов, в каждом из которых свой `ViewPager`, а не один `ViewPager` в активити. Затем из дровера вызывать эти фрагменты, которые содержат в себе собственный пэйджер. В активити только контейнер для отображения фрагмента и все. Смотрите [этот пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/236567/)

Answer (score 0):

Или у Вас одинаковый `layout` для фрагментов, или `viewPager` не обновляет адаптер.
Во втором случае может поможет [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945009/7634920) ответ